# MySQL C++ connector setBigInt

Tags: c++, mysql

So a PreparedStatement::setBigInt() takes a SQLString as the value parameter? Is there no value large enough in C++ to hold what a BigInt can hold? What if I'm using an unsigned long long in C++? What do I need to do to store this unsigned long long in a BigInt field?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bigint is a 64-bit integer, so why can't use use an `unsigned long long` for an `UNSIGNED BIGINT` column?

It might depend on what adapter you're using. Do you have a link to the reference documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Use `setUInt64` with a uint64_t:

```
void sql::PreparedStatement::setUInt64(unsigned int parameterIndex, uint64_t value);
```